# Adjusting PPT 2010 Motion Path

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have assigned a Motion Path in PPT 2010. My goal is to move an object from point A to point B. So I click the end point of the motion path and drag. Problem is, after adjusting the end point, I also notice that for whatever reason, the START point will adjust itself! So I find myself struggling with getting the object I want to move to "stay put" until it moves. When the start point moves it causes the object to "jump".

So looking for some tips about manipulating these more easily. I also notice that I'm unable to use the arrow keys to adjust only the end or start point of a motion path in fine increments.

Comment: Have you made sure you are moving it with the `resize` cursor (single arrow at an angle) and not the `move` cursor (four arrow cross)? I noticed it changes easily and can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but indeed that was the first thing I checked. I also note that only the end point moves with the drag. But when I release, both start and end points are adjusted. The weird part is that perhaps I've dragged the end point two inches. The start only moves a fraction of that. But it moves.